# sendmail to Microsoft365 (exchange)

Tags: exchange-server, sendmail, microsoft365, sendmail.exe

I want to use a email group.

I have used the sendmail.php file to have it send the mail trough a application website, into that mailbox.

sendmail.ini settings:

```
smtp_server=smtp.office365.com //Outlook settings

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
; *auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
; ssl = alway use SSL
; tls = always use TLS
; none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto
===========

if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=*full email*
auth_password=*password*
===========I even tried using POP3
pop3_server=outlook.office365.com
pop3_username=*full email*
pop3_password=*password*
===========ehlo/helo
hostname=smtp.office365.com
```

Can someone point me in a good direction,
because i also tried PHPmailer, but all i can find is outdated Google hints.

But I have tried all known combo's that I know of, and the closest I get is the STARTTLS error.
My manager want to use XAMPP with this sendmail option.
But the more I try to look into this, the more 'outdated' hints I get.

see options provided out the sendmail.ini snippet